# EditText to int in Android Studio

Tags: android, crash, parseint

My problem is that I cannot convert EditText to int. I've tried all the options I've read here, my app crashes on Open. Thank you in advance, I attach a part of my code where the problem is.
My problem starts at the first parsing-trial with 'int kg'. I have no idea what to do. The declaration is there, but not seen here. Thank you in advance.

```
private void BMISzamitas(){
 BMISzamolBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BMISzamoloBtn);
 kgEditText = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.kgEditText));
 cmEditText = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.cmEditText));
 eredmenyTextView=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.bmiEredmenyTextView));

int kg = Integer.parseInt(kgEditText.getText().toString());
int cm = Integer.parseInt(cmEditText.toString());
int m = (cm*100);

double BMI = (double)(kg/Math.pow(m, m));
eredmenyTextView.setText(new Double(BMI).toString());



}
```

Comment: Is the line after `int kg` supposed to be `int cm = Integer.parseInt(cmEditText.getText().toString());`?

Comment: Are you getting `NumberFormatException` or what?

Comment: May you provide exception stack trace (from console/logcat)? Have you got `setContentView()` method in `onCreate()`/

Comment: 1.-Yes, I accidentally deleted .getText().toString() from the code.
 And thank you for your answer, the error was that i did not check if the editText was empty and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set `inputType="number"` to your `EditText` which the user force to enter only number into the text editor to prevent exeption :

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kgEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" // this line
 />
```

then :

```
 if (!kgEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && 
            !cmEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            int kg = Integer.parseInt(kgEditText.getText().toString());
            int cm = Integer.parseInt(cmEditText.getText().toString());

        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add 'if'. now it seems working!

Answer (score 1):

You need validate that EditText wasn´t empty and add .getText() in the line

```
int cm = Integer.parseInt(cmEditText.toString());

int cm = Integer.parseInt(cmEditText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thank you but it was my mistake. :) I accidentally deleted .getText() . toString() :)